# Are there lenses which can give 180° fisheye circle with a cropped-frame camera?

Tags: lens, wide-angle, cropped-sensor, fisheye

I have a Canon EOS 1100D, and I'd like to take photos of the whole sky dome. Currently I'm using the Belomo MC 3,5/8A lens. It has 180° angle of view, but that's only true for full-frame cameras, and for the diagonal for my APS-C one. On the sides the circle doesn't fit onto the sensor.

So I wonder, is there any lens I could use to get the full 180° circle onto my cropped sensor? Or do I have to use a full-frame camera for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least the following lenses will meet your stated requirements of circular 180° image for APS-C:

- [Sigma 4.5mm ƒ/2.8 EX DC HSM](https://www.sigmaphoto.com/lenses/fisheye-lenses/45mm-f28-ex-dc-hsm-circular-fisheye)
- [Lensbaby 5.8mm ƒ/3.5 Circular Fisheye](https://lensbaby.com/product/circular-fisheye/)

If you do go with a full frame camera body, there are some more options available. Look for 8mm lenses (some are even zooms, with 8mm at the wide end). Canon, Rokinon, and Sigma all make full circle fisheye lenses for full frame bodies.

Comment: Are there any special keywords you used when searching for the two examples you listed?

Comment: Well I knew of the Sigma (because I own the 8mm full circle fisheye for full frame), and was previously aware of the Lensbaby (although I had forgotten, but my search did jog my memory). Try `aps-c 180 fisheye` and `aps-c 180 fisheye full circle` to start with. Also helpful, and probably more info than you'll ever need on what makes a lens _fisheye_, Wikipedia's [Fisheye lens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisheye_lens#Examples_and_specific_models) article.

Answer (score 4):

What you're probably looking for is **a circular fisheye lens for APS-C**. Fisheye lenses come in one of two types: circular or diagonal.  Circular ones put the entire image circle inside the frame of the sensor, while diagonal ones are more traditional and project an image circle large enough to cover the entire sensor and yield a rectangular image.

Keep in mind, however, that with a circular fisheye, you get a *lot* of black on the frame along with the image circle, so you are effectively reducing the resolution of your camera, and that with a more extreme circular fisheye, you may be trading in sharpness and chromatic aberration for the additional scene coverage, vs. a diagonal.

Most circular fisheye lenses can do 180º across both the short and long edges of the frame, but most diagonals only achieve 180º scene coverage across the diagonal (e.g., Samyang/Rokinon 8mm f/3.5 diagonal fisheye for APS-C).

Some circular fisheyes for crop include:

- Sigma 4.5mm f/2.8
- Lensbaby 5.8 f/3.5
- Meike 6.5 f/2 (rebranded as Opteka 6.5 circular sometimes)
- Yasuhara/Madoka 180 7.3mm f/4 (for mirrorless, Sony E/Fuji X)

And I even found one for MFT:

- Laowa 4mm f/2.8

So, probably digging about for Asian-made manual lenses might yield a few more candidates.

Comment: There are even ones going past 180 degrees. For example IZuggar 220 for MFT which claims an 220 degrees fov with a 3.25mm lens.